# Comparing 2 different datasets in Excel, trying to find the same entries in either set

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I have 2 excel datasets, I am trying to compare data between the 2 sets and see if the same entry shows up in both. I have 39000 entries in one and 2000 in the other, is there a quick way around it?

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://superuser.com/posts/1402785/edit) to provide sample data, expected output and what you've tried so far? As it is, we don't even know if your entries are in one cell or multiple cells...

Comment: `COUNTIF()`/`COUNTIFS()`?

Answer (score 0):

Make a third excel sheet,

Put all rows of "field to be matched" from Sheet 1 as well as from Sheet 2 into this Sheet 3.

Sort this column in Sheet 3.

Go to menu - Data - click on Remove Duplicates (in data tools), this will remove all duplicates and you will have a unique value of each data in Sheet 3

in Sheet 3 - B1, Enter =COUNTIF(Sheet1!A:A,$A1)
in Sheet 3 - C1, Enter =COUNTIF(Sheet2!A:A,$A1)

copy these formula in B1 and C1 to down the entire length of your values in A.

In B column, you have the count how many time A1 value appears in Sheet1
In C column, you have the count how many time A1 value appears in Sheet2

Comment: Will this tell me where the duplicates are?

Comment: No. That was not asked in the question.

Comment: That is why you were advised above by cybernatic to elaborate your question to tell what all output you want.

Comment: If duplicates are to be identified, just sort each individual table and put conditional formatting of showing duplicate which a direct menu command in excel. That will show duplicates next to next in a color which is different from non-duplicates' color so easily identifiable.